# Basis for rank $n$ ring containing $1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $L$ is a finite (separable?) extension of a number field $K$, $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the ring of integers of $K$, and $\mathcal{O}_L$ is the integral closure of $\mathcal{O}_K$ in $L$.

How can one prove that there is a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $\mathcal{O}_L$ over $\mathcal{O}_K$ containing $1$? Any $K$-linearly independent set can be extended to a basis of $L/K$, so there is a basis of $L/K$ containing $1$, and this basis can be scaled by clearing denominators to be contained in $\mathcal{O}_L$. So we have an integral basis for $L/K$, but is this still an $\mathcal{O}_K$-basis for $\mathcal{O}_L$?

In a more general setting, suppose that $\mathcal{O}$ is any rank $n$ ring, i.e. $\mathcal{O} \cong \bigoplus_{j=1}^n\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. How can one show that there is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $\mathcal{O}$ containing $1$?

Also, can anyone point me to a good reference to read about rank $n$ rings, a.k.a. $n$-ic rings? What is the most common terminology for them?

[Edit:]
I am grateful to KCd and Dietrich for providing counterexamples to my first question involving bases of number rings. So I consider that part sufficiently answered. However my main question is the one about the existence of such a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for a rank $n$ ring.

A *rank $n$ ring* is a ring (commutative with unity) that is *additively* isomorphic to a free abelian group of rank n. I have also heard the term *$n$-ic ring*. Rings of integers are the primary examples of rank $n$ rings, but there are other examples like direct sums of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Depending on $K$ and $L$, the ring $\mathcal O_L$ need not have *any* basis as an $\mathcal O_K$- module. An example is $K = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{-6})$ and $L = K(\sqrt{-3})$.

Comment: You don't need to say "separable" for the characteristic $0$ case. And bases are reserved for *free* modules. f we are not working over a PID we aren't guaranteed freeness of a finitely generated module, and not all $\mathcal{O}_K$ are PIDs, otherwise we would always have unique factorization.

Comment: In an abelian group $G$ isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}^n$, any element $x_1 \in G$ can be extended to a basis $x_1, \dots, x_n$ of $G$ as long as $x_1$ is not a nontrivial multiple of anything else in $G$. This clearly applies if $G = O_K$ and $x_1 = 1$.

Comment: Some details are given [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/notfree.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

For a finite field extension $L/K$ the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_L$ is a finitely generated $\mathcal{O}_K$-module, but it need not be a 
*free* $\mathcal{O}_K$-module, i.e., it need not have a basis. This is true, however, if $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a PID. A typical counter example is $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-14})$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-14},\sqrt{-7})$, where $\mathcal{O}_K$ is indeed not a PID. 
For $K=\mathbb{Q}$ of course $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a PID, and there is a basis of $\mathcal{O}_L$ over $\mathcal{O}_K$ containing $1$. 
For the second part, it seems you are talking about [free abelian groups of rank $n$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group) ?