# Number rings as free module over base ring

Tags: modules, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K \subset L$ be number fields and $\mathcal{O_K}, \mathcal{O_L}$ the corresponding rings of algebraic integers. Further let dimension$(L/K)$ = n as a vector space.

If $K$ is a PID, then $\mathcal{O_L}$ is a free module of dimension n over $\mathcal{O_K}$ (I believe this is true, please correct me if I am wrong). Is this also true in the general case and if not, can we describe the structure of $\mathcal{O_L}$ over $\mathcal{O_K}$ as a module?

Comment: In general it's basically the same, except you replace "free" with "projective."

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840059

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathcal{O_K}$ is a PID, then $\mathcal{O_L}$ is a free module over $\mathcal{O_K}$ (just use the fundamental theorem of f.g. modules over PID together with the fact that $\mathcal{O_L}$ is torsion free).
In general, it is not true that $\mathcal{O_L}$ is free over $\mathcal{O_K}$. There is a similar theorem for f.g. modules over Dedekind domains, but there the torsion free part is a direct sum of fractional ideals (which are all free if the domain is actually a PID). See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain#Finitely_generated_modules_over_a_Dedekind_domain).

For rings of integers, there are examples where the extension is not free. Moreover, in "On Integral Bases" by Henry B. Mann, it is shown that if $\mathcal{O}_K$ isn't a PID, then $K$ has a quadratic extension $L$ such that 
$\mathcal{O}_L$ is not free over $\mathcal{O}_K$, or in other words, $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a PID iff all the extensions $\mathcal{O}_L$ of integer rings are free over it.

Comment: In the first sentence, you mean $\mathcal{O_L}$ over $\mathcal{O_K}$, right? In the case that $\mathcal{O_K}$ is a PID, is the number of generators of the free module the same as $[L:K]$? Thanks for your answer, it clarified quite a bit.

Comment: @Asvin : You are right, it should be $\mathcal{O}_L$ - fixed it. In case it is free, its rank is $[L:K]$. You can see this by noting that $[\mathcal{O}_L:\mathcal{O}_K][\mathcal{O}_K:\mathbb{Z}]=[\mathcal{O}_L:\mathbb{Z}]$.

Comment: For a concrete example, there is [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1104520) answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104395/) question.